# Rails: Expected helper to define helper error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When accessing my Rails app locally, I get the following error when loading any page:

```
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Tue Jul 06 15:08:17 -0500 2010
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Expected /my_rails_app/app/helpers/admin/article_categories_helper.rb to define Admin::ArticleCategoriesHelper
```

If I follow the [full trace](https://gist.github.com/904e30559bd9c3268a07), I'm brought to this line in my application controller:

```
helper :all
```

If I comment out that line, everything appears to load fine.

Also, here's the contents of my `/admin/article_categories_helper.rb` file:

```
module Admin::ArticleCategoriesHelper
end
```

So, any ideas what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Just a note, I got this error because I was twit and put the file in the wrong folder. Ho hum

Answer (score 2):

If you try seriousken's answer and get 'xxxx is not a Module' then change it to a class.
The following worked for me.

I have: /helpers/member/finance/bank_batches_helper.rb

Within that i have:

```
module Member::Finance::BankBatchesHelper

  def some_method
    # ...
  end
end
```

Simply add the parent class(es) above as so:

```
class Member
  class Finance
  end
end

module Member::Finance::BankBatchesHelper

  def some_method
    # ...
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your file should be named

```
/admin/article_categories_helper.rb
```

instead of

```
/admin/articles_categories_helper.rb
```

Comment: Sorry, the file is actually named correctly (no "s")...was a typo in my post, which I've corrected.

Comment: What was the reason for -1? It would be good to leave a comment when doing this...

Answer (score 0):

That error often means it's had some problem loading the file in question.  Is the Admin module defined at that point?  You can try:

```
module Admin
  module ArticleCategoriesHelper
  end
end
```

instead.  This will work whether Admin exists or not.

Simplest solution would be to just remove the file entirely, since you don't seem to be using it for anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem but for me it was caused when upgrading a Rails project from Ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.2. In 1.9.2 the syntax for case statements changed. The shorthand : (colon) is no longer used. Instead you have to use the `then` keyword.

```
# works in 1.8.x
case numtype
  when 'smallint' : 4
```

The code above had to be changed to

```
# works in 1.9.2
case numtype
  when 'smallint' then 4
```

When I fixed all of the case statements in my helpers I no longer got this error.